# is geode impacted by last RCE vulnerability in the Spring Framework

Tags: spring, security, geode

is geode impacted by last RCE vulnerability in the Spring Framework ?
vulnerability details :
https://spring.io/blog/2022/03/31/spring-framework-rce-early-announcement

geode 1.14.2 has below dependencies - should spring framework used by geode upgraded to 5.3.18 ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Hi6.png

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [GEODE-10201](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-10201), it contains the information you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for share - geode is not using tomcat - so not impacted by the vulnerability